# Regex - Fail with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the next parts of text:

- "Bytes: 256K "
- "Bytes256K "
- "Bytes8356K "
- "Bytes: 756K "
- "Bytes: 56K " -> i like capture this
- "Bytes56K " -> i like capture this

I'm using the next pattern:

- /(?![0-9]{1,})56K/i

But this don't work, does any user in the community have any idea for solve this?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports look-behind then you can use:

```
(?<!\d)56K
```

`(?<!\d)` is a negative look-behind that asserts failure if there is a digit before `56K`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZWOdV/2)

Otherwise use:

```
(?:^|\D)(56K)
```

Comment: You saved me of a entire afternoon of stress. Thank you so much!